# Network Setup Service service entered the stopped state

Tags: .net, windows, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

We have recently deployed a Windows Server 2019.  We are running IIS, with a WCF service.  Connectivity to the service seems to be fine, however, in the Windows event log I'm seeing regular entries of the following :

The Network Setup Service service entered the stopped state.

The Network Setup Service service entered the running state.

[image]

How can I fix this issue?